# Errors compiling NotepadQQ. Wrong libxslt or libxml2 version perhaps?

Tags: qt, libxml2, libxslt

I'm trying to compile NotepaddQQ on a SUSE SLED 11 machine using Qt5.3 (I know.. it's crazy outdated but it's a work machine and I don't have the authority to update it) and am hitting the following error:

```
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltComputeSortResult@LIBXML2_1.0.24'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltFreeSecurityPrefs@LIBXML2_1.0.22'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `g_variant_ref'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltEvalAttrValueTemplate@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltNextImport@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltGetNsProp@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltSetSecurityPrefs@LIBXML2_1.0.22'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltSetCtxtSecurityPrefs@LIBXML2_1.0.22'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltTransformError@LIBXML2_1.0.22'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltNewSecurityPrefs@LIBXML2_1.0.22'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltNewTransformContext@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltParseStylesheetDoc@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltRegisterExtFunction@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `g_variant_unref'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltFreeTransformContext@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltSetLoaderFunc@LIBXML2_1.1.9'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltSaveResultTo@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: undefined reference to `xsltApplyStylesheetUser@LIBXML2_1.0.11'
etc....
```

I'm not sure what the @LIBXML2_### suffix means???
But I managed to find out what version of libxml2 and libxslt version I have:

```
$ xsltproc --version
Using libxml 20706, libxslt 10124 and libexslt 813
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20701, libxslt 10124 and libexslt 813
libxslt 10124 was compiled against libxml 20701
libexslt 813 was compiled against libxml 20701
```

Is there an incompatibility somewhere?
Thanks...

EDIT:

```
$ ldd ~/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so
/usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: /usr/lib64/libxslt.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so)
/usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: /usr/lib64/libxslt.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so)
/usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: /usr/lib64/libxslt.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so)
/usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so: /usr/lib64/libxslt.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fac018f2000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fabff0df000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fabfeec8000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fabfecbe000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fabfeabb000)
    libicui18n.so.52 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00007fabfe69a000)
    libicuuc.so.52 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007fabfe312000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fabfdfd5000)
    libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007fabfdd99000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fabfda3d000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fabfd777000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fabfd532000)
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fabfd249000)
    libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fabfd03c000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fabfcde8000)
    libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fabfcbd7000)
    libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fabfc9b5000)
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fabfc7a7000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007fabfc1f2000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007fabfbbdd000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fabfb878000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fabfb144000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fabfaf27000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fabfa801000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007fabfa5c0000)
    libQt5Positioning.so.5 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5 (0x00007fabfa381000)
    libQt5Sensors.so.5 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Sensors.so.5 (0x00007fabfa140000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fabf9eba000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fabf9bb4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fabf993a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fabf95be000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fac018f3000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fabf93b8000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fabf91a5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fabf8f8f000)
    libicudata.so.52 => /usr2/acourche/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007fabf7723000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fabf751f000)
    libxcb-xlib.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xlib.so.0 (0x00007fabf731d000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fabf7100000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fabf6efc000)
    libpcre.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x00007fabf6ccc000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fabf6ac6000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fabf68c2000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fabf666a000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fabf6467000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fabf6264000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fabf604e000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fabf5e48000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fabf5c3b000)
```

Comment: Execute  `ldd Qt5.3/5.3/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so` and show us the result

Comment: The error messages indicate you're using Qt 5.3, but in the question you mention you're using 5.5. Which is it?

Comment: Added additional info. And sorry yes it's Qt5.3

Comment: I haven't used SUSE, but could it be related to missing development libraries? In Debian, you'd have something like `libxml2-dev` that would be needed for compilation.

Comment: install this: `libxslt-devel`

Comment: Yeah I though about that. Installed libxslt-devel as well and still get same error. 
<code>$ zypper search libxslt 
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                | Summary                                               | Type      
--+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------
i | libxslt             | XSL Transformation Library                            | package   
i | libxslt-devel       | Include Files and Libraries mandatory for Development | package </code>

Comment: Is it because this verion of Qt4WebKit is expecting a much older version of libxslt?

Answer (score 0):

The `@LIBXML2_` suffix comes from ELF symbol versioning. It seems that `libQt5WebKit.so` was built with a version of libxslt that had versioned symbols, but your system libxslt was built without versioned symbols. So `libQt5WebKit.so` was apparently not built with your system libxslt, maybe on another machine.

You have two options:

- Rebuild `libQt5WebKit.so` using your system libxslt.
- Build a separate version of libxslt with versioned symbols and use it when compiling NotepadQQ.